# how can I get matched groups from regex match function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group

basically I'm trying to get imported modules name with regex, and I got my regex right. so I used this in code but I get weird stuffs not module names. What I want to get is, `adsf` string which is in **group #1**.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
for(let js of jsFiles) {
    const codes = await fs.readFile(js, 'utf8')
    const regex = /(?:from |require\()'([^/.][^/]*?)'/g
    let arr = codes.match(regex)
    console.log("arr", arr)
  }
```

and Here's the output.

```
arr [ 'require(\'fs-extra\'' ]
arr [ 'require(\'fs-extra\'', 'require(\'path\'' ]
arr [ 'require(\'babel-polyfill\'',
  'require(\'child-process-promise\'',
  'require(\'fs-extra\'',
  'require(\'chalk\'',
  'require(\'ora\'',
  'require(\'querystring\'' ]
arr [ 'from \'ora\'', 'from \'fs-extra\'', 'from \'glob-promise\'' ]
arr [ 'from \'fs-extra\'' ]
arr [ 'from \'fs-extra\'' ]
arr [ 'from \'chalk\'', 'from \'ora\'' ]
arr null
arr null
arr [ 'require(\'bluebird\'', 'require(\'child_process\'' ]
arr null
arr [ 'from \'child-process-promise\'',
  'from \'chalk\'',
  'from \'ora\'' ]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post those screenshots as plain text. Ideally with the markup you used for the text you already pasted!

Comment: @csabinho I just updated it. thanks for the feedback

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match - If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method returns null. - What happens when you don't include the g

Comment: @JasonB I need to get module name as many as they are in a js file. so that's why I put the g flag but It matches the whole string like `require(\'fs-extra\'` when I need `fs-extra`. and It returns the module name right when I remove g flag but I only get one module name.

Comment: Instead of `codes.match(regex)` use `regex.exec(codes)` in a loop: then you will have the captured text for each group.

Comment: @trincot when I use `regex.exec(codes)`, result is the same as the output when I remove g flag with `.match` function. It doesn't get me multiple matched objects.

Comment: Result is not the same. I have posted the idea as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `codes.match(regex)` use `regex.exec(codes)` in a loop: then you will have the captured text for each group.

Example for one input:

```js
const codes = `
    require('babel-polyfill');
    require('child-process-promise');
    require('fs-extra');
    require('chalk');
    require('ora');
    require('querystring');
`;
const regex = /(?:from |require\()'([^/.][^/]*?)'/g,
    arr = [];
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(codes)) arr.push(match[1]);
console.log("arr", arr)
```

Note that `match[1]` represents what was matched for the first capture group. `match[0]` would give you the complete match, like with the `match` method (when used with `g` modifier).